# How to integrate IBM bluemix Retrieve and rank web interface into IOS app?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson, retrieve-and-rank

I went through the ios sdk on github. But didn't understand the following parameters:

retrieveAndRank.searchAndRank(
    withCollectionName: collectionName,
    fromSolrClusterID: cluster.solrClusterID,
    rankerID: ranker.rankerID,
    query: "your-query-here",
    returnFields: "your-return-fields-here",
    failure: failure)
{
    response in
    print(response)
}

Comment: Your question is vague. Can you please help us understand what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the cluster ID and collection name on the Clusters screen.

[image: Clusters screen]

You can find the ranker ID on the Performance screen.

[image: Performance screen]

For fields, I'd suggest `title,body`.

And the query is the question text that you want to search for.

Hope that helps!